# Search videos according to videoCategoryId in youtube API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to search youtube videos which is not fall in specific `videoCategoyId`.  I know this option is used to select a specific type of videos which id is given in this part but I want to get those videos which is not related to this id which is given in `videoCategoryId`.
Like `videoCategoryId != 10`.

```
 GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=3&q=Wajah+Tum+Ho+HD+Video+&safeSearch=strict&type=video&videoCategoryId != 10&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Ftitle&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

How can I do this.
Thanks....

Comment: [Issue tracker posted](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205873422).